# prove F(S,R) is a vector space over R by checking the axioms.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a question for checking vector space axiom 3 (There exists an element in V denoted by 0 such that x+0=x for each x in V.)

My proof for this axiom is that define function H:S$\to$0 and $x \in V$. By field axiom A4 (F contains an element 0 such that 0+x=x for every $x \in$ F), we get x+0=x $\rightarrow$ 0+0=0. Hence proved. Is it ok?

Comment: Fourth axiom is the same as the third axiom?

Comment: third axiom is for vector space, which is the same as the fourth axiom in field axiom.

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry. I didn't see the word *axiom*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to define the function $H$ (which I will denote it by $\mathbf 0$). And, in this case $F=\mathbb R$, so, the element $0$ such that $0+x = x+0 = x$ is simply the real number zero. Hence, you would to define $\mathbf0 \in \mathcal{F}(S,\mathbb R)$ just as $\mathbf0(s) = 0$, that is, $H$ is the function that sends every $s\in S$ to $0$.

Therefore, for every $f\in \textsf{V} = \mathcal{F}(S,\mathbb R)$, we have
$$(f+\mathbf0)(s) = f(s) + \mathbf0(s) = f(s) + 0 = f(s)$$
so, $f+\mathbf0 =f$ as we want to show.